# How to use PullToRefresh in childFragment

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using `PullToRefresh` to refresh the `ListView`which is inside Child Fragment(nested fragment) but when I pull it down, some loading animation appears but it doesn't make any changes in list. It shows only the previous loaded data.

here is my code:-

```
    public class OzoneFeedFragment extends Fragment implements MiFeelingBase, OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<OzoneFeedData>arrOzoneFeed;
    private ArrayList<OzoneFeedData>arrList=new ArrayList<OzoneFeedData>();
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    private OzoneAdapter adpter;

    private LinearLayout llUserPost;
    private TextView tvUserPost;
    private String strUserID;
    private String strServerKey;
    //private ListView lv;
    private int page=0;
    private boolean loadingMore=false;
    View loadMoreView;
    int UrlIndex=0;
     // private DatabaseHandler databaseHelper;
        //private SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = null;
        private PullToRefreshListView llList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ozone_feed, container, false);
         llUserPost=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.llUserPost);
         llUserPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         tvUserPost=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvWhatOnYourMind);
         tvUserPost.setOnClickListener(this);
         llList=(PullToRefreshListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
       loadMoreView = ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null, false);

       llList.addFooterView(loadMoreView);

         Reload();

      //   llList = (PullToRefreshListView) getView();
         llList.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                llList.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        llList.onRefreshComplete();

                           APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
                           UrlIndex=0;
                            adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });

        llList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(visibleItemCount>0)
                {
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; 
                if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore))
                {
                     APIAccess.fetchPagingData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity(),true);
                }
                }
            }
        });

      //   llList = (PullToRefreshListView) getView();


          return rootView;
}

    private void Reload() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity(),true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

         //UrlIndex=0;
         //APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
         //notifyAll();
         //adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        adpter=null;
        page=0;
        loadingMore=false;
        arrList.clear();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          AppContoller.getInstance().pref=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppContoller.getInstance().PREF_NAME, 0);

          try{

            strUserID=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().USER_ID, "0");
            strServerKey=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().SERVER_KEY, "0");
          }catch(Exception e){

          }

            System.out.println("login detail  " + strUserID + "  " + strServerKey);

         APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public String httpPost() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String response="";
        if(UrlIndex==0){
        loadingMore=true;
        page++;
        response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OPOST+"id/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey+"/page/"+page);

        }
        else if(UrlIndex==1){

            loadingMore=true;
            page++;

            response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OPOST+"id/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey+"/page/"+page);
            }
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    public String httpAfterPost(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(str!=null)
        {
            if(UrlIndex==0){

        arrOzoneFeed=SabaKuchParse.parseOzoneFeed(str);
        if(arrOzoneFeed.size()>0)
        {
            loadingMore=false;
            arrList.addAll(arrOzoneFeed);
            if(adpter==null)
            { 
            adpter=new OzoneAdapter(getActivity(), arrList);
            llList.setAdapter(adpter);
            adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else
            {
                adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
            else if(UrlIndex==1){
                arrOzoneFeed=SabaKuchParse.parseOzoneFeed(str);
                if(arrOzoneFeed.size()>0)
                {
                    loadingMore=false;
                    arrList.addAll(arrOzoneFeed);
                    adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if(adpter==null)
                    {
                    adpter=new OzoneAdapter(getActivity(), arrList);
                    llList.setAdapter(adpter);
                    }else

                    {
                        adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),OUserPostActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

> Here is my OzoneAdapter Class

```
     public OzoneAdapter(Context cxt,ArrayList<OzoneFeedData>arr)

    {
        this.cxt=cxt;
        this.arr=arr;


        try{
         AppContoller.getInstance().pref=cxt.getSharedPreferences(AppContoller.getInstance().PREF_NAME, 0);

            strUserID=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().USER_ID, "0");
            strServerKey=AppContoller.getInstance().pref.getString(AppContoller.getInstance().SERVER_KEY, "0");
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) cxt).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.ozone_feed_item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.userImage=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

            holder.userImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            holder.LocationPhoto=(NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.LocationImage);
            holder.tvName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.tvFavCount=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFavCount);
            holder. tvShareinfo=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSharedInfohh);

            holder.rvshare=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativesahrecount);
            holder.rvreply=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativereplycount);
            holder.rvfav=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativefaveecount);


        **Initializing the elements**

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              System.out.println("Show button");
              holder.show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              holder.hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              holder. tvContent.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

             }
            });

        holder.hide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              System.out.println("Hide button");
              holder.hide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              holder.show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              holder.tvContent.setMaxLines(1);

             }
            });



        Picasso.with(cxt) //
        .load(arr.get(position).strUserImage).transform(new CircleTransform())
        .noFade()//
        .error(R.drawable.loader)
        .resize(200, 200)
        .centerCrop()// Keep proportion
        .into((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic));


        if(arr.get(position).strreportinfo.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
           holder.tvShareinfo.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }else
            {
                holder.tvShareinfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.tvShareinfo.setText(arr.get(position).strreportinfo +"Shared post by"+arr.get(position).strName);
            }

    holder.tvShareinfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OUserProfileDetail.class);


            i.putExtra("userid", arr.get(position).strreportinfoid);
            i.putExtra("username", arr.get(position).strreportinfo);


            cxt.startActivity(i);


        }
    });

        if(arr.get(position).strTweetLocation.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            holder.tvTweetLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else 
        {
            holder.tvTweetLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvTweetLocation.setText(arr.get(position).strTweetLocation);

        }


        holder.tvName.setText(arr.get(position).strName);

        holder.tvFavCount.setText(arr.get(position).strFavouriteCount);

        holder.tvReplyCount.setText(arr.get(position).strReplyCount);

        holder.tvShareCount.setText(arr.get(position).strRetweetCount);

        holder.tvTimeStamp.setText(StaticData.convertDate(arr.get(position).strCreatedDate));

        if(arr.get(position).strContent.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
        holder.tvContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }else
        {
            holder.tvContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ssp = arr.get(position).strContent;

            Log.d("sspppp", ssp);
            ssp = ssp.replace("\n", "<br>");
            Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(ssp);
            Log.d("sssspppp2", sp.toString());
            holder.tvContent.setText(sp);
            holder.tvContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }

        if(arr.get(position).strContent.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            holder.show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else if(arr.get(position).strContent.length()<100){

            holder.show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else if(arr.get(position).strContent.length()>100){

            holder.show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


        if(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.size()>0)
        {

            if(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.size()==1)
            {

        holder.feedImageView1.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(0), imageLoader);
        holder.feedImageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.feedImageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.feedImageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.feedImageView1.setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() 
                    {
                        //
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() 
                    {
                        //
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.size()==2)
            {
                holder.feedImageView1.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(0), imageLoader);
                holder.feedImageView2.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(1), imageLoader);
                holder.feedImageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.feedImageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.feedImageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holder.feedImageView1.setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
              holder.feedImageView2.setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

            }
            else if(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.size()>=3)
            {
                holder.feedImageView1.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(0), imageLoader);
                holder.feedImageView2.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(1), imageLoader);
                holder.feedImageView3.setImageUrl(arr.get(position).arrTweetImage.get(2), imageLoader);
                holder.feedImageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.feedImageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.feedImageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
        else
       {
   holder.feedImageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.feedImageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.feedImageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

        // Click Listener



        holder.rvfav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                urlIndex=0;
                selectedPosition=position;
                APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneAdapter.this, cxt, (Activity)cxt);
            }
        });

        holder.rvshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                urlIndex=2;
               selectedPosition=position;
               APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneAdapter.this, cxt, (Activity)cxt);
            }
        });

        holder.rvreply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OReplyActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("tweet_id", arr.get(position).strTweetID);
                i.putExtra("obj", arr.get(position));
                cxt.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.ivHide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                selectedPosition=position;
                getPopupWindow();

               popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, -5, 0);    
            }
        });

             holder.ivfavourite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                urlIndex=0;
                selectedPosition=position;
                APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneAdapter.this, cxt, (Activity)cxt);
            }
        });

        holder.userImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OUserProfileDetail.class);

                i.putExtra("userid", arr.get(position).strUserID);
                i.putExtra("username", arr.get(position).strName);


                cxt.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.feedImageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OImageDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("obj", arr.get(position));
                cxt.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
holder.feedImageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OImageDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("obj", arr.get(position));
                cxt.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

holder.feedImageView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(cxt,OImageDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("obj", arr.get(position));
        cxt.startActivity(i);
    }
}); 
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public String httpPost() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String response="";
        if(urlIndex==0)
        {
        response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OFAV_OUNFAV+"post_id/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID+"/userid/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey);
        }else if(urlIndex==1)
        {
            response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OPOSTDELETE+"id/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID+"/userid/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey);
        }
        else if(urlIndex==2)
        {
            response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OSHAREPOST+"post_id/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID+"/userid/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey);
        }
        else if(urlIndex==3) {

            response=OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OMUTEPOST+"id/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID+"/login_id/"+strUserID+"/userid/"+strUserID+"/check/mute/key/"+strServerKey);
        }
        else if(urlIndex==4)
        {
            postUserBlock();
            response=APIAccess.openConnection(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OMUTEPOST, reqEntity);
             //response = OpenConnection.callUrl(StaticData.SABAKUCH_OMUTEPOST+"post_id/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID+"/ownerid/"+arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID+"/userid/"+strUserID+"/key/"+strServerKey); 
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public String httpAfterPost(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(str!=null)
        {
            if(urlIndex==0)
            {
            if(SabaKuchParse.parseFavData(str).equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
            {

            }else
            {
                OzoneFeedData obj=new OzoneFeedData();
                obj.strContent=arr.get(selectedPosition).strContent;
                obj.strCreatedDate=arr.get(selectedPosition).strCreatedDate;
                obj.strFavouriteCount=SabaKuchParse.parseFavData(str);
                obj.strGender=arr.get(selectedPosition).strGender;
                obj.strlat=arr.get(selectedPosition).strlat;
                obj.strlon=arr.get(selectedPosition).strlon;
                obj.strName=arr.get(selectedPosition).strName;
                obj.strreportinfo=arr.get(selectedPosition).strreportinfo;
                obj.strReplyCount=arr.get(selectedPosition).strReplyCount;
                obj.strRetweetCount=arr.get(selectedPosition).strRetweetCount;
                obj.strTweetID=arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID;
                obj.strTweetLocation=arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetLocation;
                obj.strUserID=arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID;
                obj.strUserImage=arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserImage;
                obj.arrTweetImage=arr.get(selectedPosition).arrTweetImage;

                arr.set(selectedPosition, obj);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            }
            else if(urlIndex==1)
            {
                if(SabaKuchParse.jsonStatus(str)==1)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(cxt, SabaKuchParse.jsonErrorMessage(str), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    arr.remove(selectedPosition);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(cxt, SabaKuchParse.jsonErrorMessage(str), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }else if(urlIndex==2)
            {
                if(SabaKuchParse.parseShareData(str).equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    OzoneFeedData obj = new OzoneFeedData();
                    obj.strContent=arr.get(selectedPosition).strContent;
                    obj.strCreatedDate=arr.get(selectedPosition).strCreatedDate;
                    obj.strFavouriteCount=arr.get(selectedPosition).strFavouriteCount;
                    obj.strGender=arr.get(selectedPosition).strGender;
                    obj.strlat=arr.get(selectedPosition).strlat;
                    obj.strlon=arr.get(selectedPosition).strlon;
                    obj.strName=arr.get(selectedPosition).strName;
                    obj.strReplyCount=arr.get(selectedPosition).strReplyCount;
                    obj.strRetweetCount=SabaKuchParse.parseShareData(str);
                    obj.strreportinfo=arr.get(selectedPosition).strreportinfo;
                    obj.strTweetID=arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID;
                    obj.strTweetLocation=arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetLocation;
                    obj.strUserID=arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID;
                    obj.strUserImage=arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserImage;
                    obj.arrTweetImage=arr.get(selectedPosition).arrTweetImage;

                    arr.set(selectedPosition, obj);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                }
                else if(urlIndex==3){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
                    if(jsonObj.getJSONObject("feeds").getInt("succeses")==1)
                    {
                //  Toast.makeText(cxt, jsonObj.getJSONObject("feeds").getString("msessage"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                        arr.remove(selectedPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }

            }else if(urlIndex==4)
            {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
                    if(jsonObj.getJSONObject("feeds").getInt("successes")==1)
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(cxt, jsonObj.getJSONObject("feeds").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        arr.remove(selectedPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
}
        return null;
    }
    public void postUserBlock()
    {
        try
        {
         StringBody post_id=new StringBody(arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID);
         StringBody key=new StringBody(strServerKey);
         StringBody userid=new StringBody(strUserID);
         StringBody ownerid=new StringBody(arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID);
         StringBody block=new StringBody("block");

        reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        reqEntity.addPart("post_id", post_id);
        reqEntity.addPart("key", key);
        reqEntity.addPart("userid", userid);
        reqEntity.addPart("ownerid", ownerid);
        reqEntity.addPart("block", block);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("err" + e);
        }

    }

    public void getPopupWindow()
    {

        popupWindow=new PopupWindow(cxt);
        ListView popList=new ListView(cxt);
        ArrayList<String>arrPopItem=new ArrayList<String>();
    //  selectedPosition ;
        arrPopItem.add("Mute");
        arrPopItem.add("Block or Spam");
        //String ID =arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID;
    //  Log.d("hdfu", ID);
        if(strUserID.equalsIgnoreCase(arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID))
        {
            arrPopItem.remove("Mute");
            arrPopItem.remove("Block or Spam");
            arrPopItem.add("Delete");

        //  POPVALUE ="Delete";
        }
        PopupAdapter adpter=new PopupAdapter(arrPopItem);
        popList.setAdapter(adpter);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setWidth(200);
        popupWindow.setContentView(popList);

    }

    private class PopupAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
      ArrayList<String> arrPop;
    public  PopupAdapter (ArrayList<String>arr)
    {
    this.arrPop=arr;

    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrPop.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v=convertView;

            if(v==null)
            {
                v=View.inflate(cxt, R.layout.popup_window_row, null);
                /*NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView)v
                        .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
                profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/

                TextView tvCategery=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPopuptext);

                tvCategery.setText(arrPop.get(position));
                tvCategery.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                tvCategery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    //String uu =arr.get(position).strName;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if((position==2))
                        {
                        urlIndex=3;
                        APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneAdapter.this, cxt, (Activity)cxt);
                        }else if(position==0)
                        {
                            urlIndex=3;
                            APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneAdapter.this, cxt, (Activity)cxt);
                        }else if(position==1)
                        {
                            Intent i =new Intent(cxt,Ozonespamactivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("postid", arr.get(selectedPosition).strTweetID);


                            i.putExtra("name", arr.get(selectedPosition).strName);
                            i.putExtra("userid", arr.get(selectedPosition).strUserID);

                            cxt.startActivity(i);
                        }

                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                //profilePic.setImageUrl(StaticData.MIF_PROFILE_IMG_URL+arr.get(position).strCatRelativePath+"/"+arr.get(position).strCatID+".jpg", imageLoader);

            }
               return v;
        }
    }
```

Please let me know that what I am missing here.

Comment: I always chuckle when I see `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` still in the code ... Boy, this code is a mess !

Comment: @2Dee so that is why you marked this question negative???

Comment: @2Dee this code is a part of social networking application. there are lots of things we have to done at same time.. and there is no mess brother, I am just using interface.

Comment: No mess ? This is mostly code copied from a sample you found somewhere, it's full of unnecessary commented code, wierd spaces, wrong identation, ... For example, why do you override `onResume` just to call `super.onResume` ?? This would get so many -1 on a real company code review that there would be not enough space to show them on a 42inch screen... Byt hey, by all means, have it your way, I'm just trying to point out that by not posting clean code, you're less likely to get useful answers. Don't get me started on the usefulness of your question, though...

Comment: APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity());It's sync or async?

Comment: @2Dee hahah, No brother, Actually I tried all the methods to refresh the page, call the api again in different different methods. And for YI , I wrote this code, No where you will find interface to use json and parsing data from api.

Comment: You should move APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity()); into  onRefresh()  , not in the handler.postDelay.And If fetchData is async,you should move adpter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to when the data callback.

Comment: @tinysunlight thnk you for your feed , but brother it did not work. it remain same.

Comment: Plz Log.e("callback") or toast sth in httpAfterPost to check if Data callBack.

Comment: @tinysunlight hello bro, Sorry for reply so late, I have added Log.e("") and yes it got printed.

Comment: adpter=new OzoneAdapter(getActivity(), arrList); .And add a setter and a  getter for arrList in OzoneAdapter .When data is changed . setArrList(newarrList) before notifyDataChanged().

Comment: Debug to Check if you reach   adpter=new OzoneAdapter(getActivity(), arrList); llList.setAdapter(adpter);

Comment: @tinysunlight thnk you brother, let me check what are you saying, I will let u know.

Comment: @tinysunlight do you want to see OzoneAdapter class???

Comment: @Devraj Add if you can.

Comment: @tinysunlight plzz see, I have added adapter class

Comment: 1.Can you use some fake data to show the list?

Comment: @tinysunlight can u give me ur email so i can give you the apk file, you can easily understand what is the issue??

Comment: string2015s@gmail.com.Can you pass source code to me?

Comment: @tinysunlight Hey bro, Thank u so much for your assistance, It is so kind of you. Brother I resolved my issue. you can see my answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all your support. I have resolved the issue I had.

I just added cleared the listview before adding new items just after calling refresh() method.

```
llList.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                //llList.setAdapter(null);
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new OzoneFragment();

                 APIAccess.fetchData(OzoneFeedFragment.this, getActivity(), getActivity());

                llList.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        llList.onRefreshComplete();
                        //messageList = new ArrayList<MessageBean>();

                           UrlIndex=0;

                           arrList.clear(); //this is what I did torefresh the list 

                            adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.e("check", "check");
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```